# Server deployment using git hooks not working

Tags: git, ubuntu, server, vps

While using windows 10 in local machine and ubuntu vps server, I am trying to make auto deployment using git hooks from local to server. I configured my ubuntu server as following :

```
root@server:~# cd /var
root@server:~# mkdir repo && cd repo
root@server:~# mkdir site.git && cd site.git
root@server:~# git init --bare
root@server:~# cd hooks
root@server:~# touch post-receive && nano post-receive
```

and modified `post-receive` as following

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/site--git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

After that in the local pc repo I executated the following command

```
git remote add production ssh://root@example.com/var/repo/site.git
```

now in local repo I've 3 branches like `master, branch1, branch2`. When I push the repo to server by
`git push production master` it pushed the master branch to server. But when I push `git push production branch1`, it doesn't pushed the branch1. In `/var/www/site` I found the master branch.

So I have two questions:

1. How can I push other branches(not the master) to server.
2. If I need to delete the production branch from local machine & add new server destination how to do so ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="/var/www/site"
GIT_DIR="/var/repo/site.git"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
        echo "Ref $ref received. Deploying ${newrev} to production..."
        git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f $newrev
done
```

Without specifying a branch or commit on the checkout command will checkout the existing head again.

Comment: That worked & made my day, thanks !! Looking forward for the answer of second question .

Comment: Not sure if I understand the second question correctly.

Comment: By running `git remote add production ssh://root@example.com/var/repo/site.git` I'm creating a production branch in my local machine, by which it will deploy the app to server. Now when I try to delete or modify this production branch from local machine by `git branch -d production`, I'm facing some trouble. Is there any specific way to delete this branch ?

Comment: By running `git remote add production` you do not create a remote branch. You create add references to a remote repository. Branch is created when you push the branch.

Comment: Then how can I delete this reference ?